# Unable to find resource ID. which one?

Tags: android-studio

I am getting below error. Error log says that its unable to find the resource ID. which ID, I am still clueless

```
11-03 09:59:32.821 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f040019 (t=3 e=25) (error -75)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs, PID: 9269
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs.hrm.HRSActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040019
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040019
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2774)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1165)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs.hrm.HRSActivity.onCreateView(HRSActivity.java:46)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs.profile.BleProfileActivity.onCreate(BleProfileActivity.java:68)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
11-03 09:59:32.843 9269-9269/com.example.ospunelap_130.hrs
```

Error : **Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040019**

```
Also Please tell me how dd you concluded the resource ID.

TIA :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of `HRSActivity#onCreateView()` you are calling `setContentView(...)` which will attempt to inflate the layout you indicate with an ID (something like `R.layout.hrs_activity`)

First thing I recommend is that you verify you are passing it a valid layout ID and not any other type. The fact that you have a legitimate ID tells me that you likely passed in a type other than layout.

Comment: I did two changes and it worked.1) Moved the layout file from layout_x folder to layout.2) added 'super.onCreate(savedInstancestate);'
Is this the right way to do? also could you please explain what super.Oncreate does? I am new t this and really confused :(

Comment: If you want to use custom folder names for your resources you can but you will need to add them to the source set in your build.gradle file like this [github repo shows](https://github.com/eskimoapps/ResourceNestingExample). I recommend doing this on large projects to stay organized.

By calling the super.Oncreate() you are calling the OnCreate method of the class you are extending. When overriding methods on android activities this is usually required but not always since you can use an override to completely change the behavior of the method. @Neha